# Why is flink UI not showing the right numbers?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running a flink job, which takes two data sources and joins them.

The output of the join is a dataStream. But I also emit a sideoutput if the join fails. Now I pass the dataStream from the sideoutput through a ProcessFunction that looks up the missed joined data from the source of truth and generates an enriched record

I take the union of the original joined dataStream with the stream coming out of the processed sideoutput and pass it through a sink

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the sideoutput after being processed is alreadyemitting 95 records while the sink input 37,280 only matches with what came out of join operator

I just do

```
unionedDataStream = joinedDataStream.union(processedSideOutputStream);
unionedDataStream.addSink(sink)
```

Now if I log the records going to the sink, I could see the ones coming from the sideoutput as well. However, it's only the numbers that are not matching. Is it an issue with the UI or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [FLINK-27944](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-27944), which was fixed in Flink 1.17.0, and backported to 1.15.4 and 1.16.1.

Comment: I am using flink version 1.17.0